# Access Node within node using SAX Parser

Tags: java, saxparser

I have a XML structure like this

```
<pre><code>
   <testsuite name="TestCase1" failures=2>
      <testcase>
         <failure>Failure Reason</failure>
      </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite>
      <testcase>
      </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</code></pre>
```

If the failures are more than zero, then I need to print the TestSuite name, number of failures and Failure  Reason. How do I do that using SAXParser?

Comment: <pre><code> 
    <testsuite name="TestCase1" failures=2>
    <testcase>
    <failure>Failure Reason</failure>
    </testcase>
    <testsuite>
    <testcase>
    </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</code></pre>

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279339/2135838 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119902/2135838